# Call PHP on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following button:

```
<input type="submit" name="kudos_button" value="★ Give kudos"/>'
```

And for testing purpose, I made a PHP script like this after the `</html>`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['kudos_button'])){
        $message = "Pressed";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        //and then execute a sql query here
    }
?>
```

It all works fine, when pressing the `kudos_button` the message shows up. But the problem is that when the user refreshes the page, the message shows up again. And I get the following message:

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered.
> Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated.
> Do you want to continue?

Any tips how I can avoid this, so the button does not press again when refreshing?

Comment: You should use GET method instead of POST.

Comment: @mishanon If I change from `if(isset($_POST['kudos_button'])){` to `if(isset($_GET['kudos_button'])){`, nothing happen when pressing the button.

Comment: you need to set the button in a `<form>` Tag and gave this one a action. A simple button click can only handled by JS.eventListener.

Comment: You likely are looking for AJAX. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I really wouldn't use jQuery just for an Ajax helper in 2020. The native APIs are good now.

Comment: @RyffLe Can you give an example please? I see the answer below but that looks vuln to XSS injections. EDIT: I tried like this: `echo '<form method="get"> <input type="submit" name="kudos_button" value="★ Gi kudos"/> </form>';` but still same issue.

Comment: @AmenCarb — GET won't help you at all. It's wildly inappropriate for the task too.

Comment: I updated my answer. The form is the same as in the first solution. The script I wrote in PHP is in the `---Edit---` Section.

Comment: This is just user error really - if you refresh a form submission action then it'll submit the form again. That's why the browser issues the warning asking it they really wanted to do that - that's standard browser functionality in this scenario, nothing specific you your code. The question would be why they felt the need to refresh the page in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <input type="submit" name="kudos_button" value="★ Give kudos"/>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['kudos_button'])){
        $message = "Pressed";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        //and then execute a sql query here
    }
?>
```

Should be worke fine.

But you should know that PHP works regardless of the alert. Either way, your SQL statement will be executed after the button is pressed.

JavaScript is a Client Based Script and PHP a Server Based Script two different things.

--- EDIT ---

I builded a Function Based PHP Script which is calling the alert and feel for 5 seconds to sleep so the alert can shown up.

Here is my finished solution:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="./" >
    <input type="submit" name="kudos_button" value="★ Give kudos"/>
</form>

            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['kudos_button'])){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION["Button_onClick"] = 1;
                    $message = "Pressed";
                    if ($_SESSION["Button_onClick"] == 1) {
                        Button_onClick();
                        $_SESSION["Button_onClick"] = 0;
                        if ($_SESSION["Button_onClick"] == 0) {
                            BackLoop();
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Function Button_onClick(){
                    $message = "Pressed";
                    echo ("
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            alert('$message');
                        </script>
                    ");
                    SQL_Statement();
                }
                
                Function SQL_Statement() {
                    //and then execute a sql query here
                }
                
                Function BackLoop() {
                    session_destroy();
                    echo("
                        <script>
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                //Redirect with JavaScript
                                window.location.href= './';
                            }, 5000);
                        </script>
                    ");
                }
            ?>
```

Just in case for that someone have questions. I added the setTimeout function so I could see the changes on the website. If you don't want any infos after the alert (user case), you can delete the function. You only need `window.location.href= './';`.

Comment: That's the same approach that the OP is using, with the same problem.

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` opens OP to XSS injections.

Comment: instad of `<form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >` you also can use `<form name="form1" method="POST" action="./" >`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to navigate to a new page, then you can't use a regular form submission.

Make the HTTP request with JavaScript instead.

e.g.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const responseHandler = response => response.json();
const dataHandler = data => {
    alert(data.message);
};
const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const url = "/path/to/dedicated/webservice/that/returns/json";
    fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: data }).then(responseHandler).then(dataHandler);
};
form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

MDN has [a guide on using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Then your server-side code would look something like:

```
<?php
// Execute a sql query here

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$message = "Pressed";
echo json_encode( [ message => $message ] );
```